# Why aren't the tables created after migration? No migrations were applied

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create database , but after `context.Database.Migrate(); Database creates without problem, but always no tables are created except _EFMigrationHistory (empty). So may you help me to find source of problem or advice how to continue investigation?

There is my dbcontext:

```
public class CatalogDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CatalogItem> CatalogItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CatalogBrand> CatalogBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogTypes { get; set; }

    public CatalogDBContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogDBContext> options) : base(options) 
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new CLoggerEFInterceptor());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new BrandEntityTypeConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new TypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ItemEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Program:

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CatalogDBContext>();
    var env = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
    var settings = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CatalogSettings>>();
    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CatalogDBSeedData>>();

    context.Database.Migrate();

    new CatalogDBSeedData().SeedAsync(context, env, settings, logger).Wait();
}
```

And migration:

```
public partial class InitialMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
                name: "brand_hilo",
                incrementBy: 10);

            migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
                name: "item_hilo",
                incrementBy: 10);

            migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
                name: "type_hilo",
                incrementBy: 10);

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Brand",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Brand", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Type",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Type", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Item",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false),
                    PictureFileName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    TypeId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                    BrandId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                    AvailableStock = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    RestockThreshold = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    MaxStockThreshold = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    OnReorder = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Item", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Item_Brand_BrandId",
                        column: x => x.BrandId,
                        principalTable: "Brand",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Item_Type_TypeId",
                        column: x => x.TypeId,
                        principalTable: "Type",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Item_BrandId",
                table: "Item",
                column: "BrandId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Item_TypeId",
                table: "Item",
                column: "TypeId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Item");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Brand");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Type");

            migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
                name: "brand_hilo");

            migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
                name: "item_hilo");

            migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
                name: "type_hilo");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
base.OnModelCreating(builder);
```

into your `OnModelCreating` method

I've got similar situation months ago and this solved problem for me